# Defining multiple variables at once in one line with one value?

Tags: python

Ok so basically I want to define 4 separate variable by all the same value simultaneously.

Is it possible to do something along the lines of this?

```
a, b, c, d = 4
```

where all four variables separately equal 4?

Comment: Wasn't this already asked earlier today?

Comment: Indeed, only 4 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661879/assign-many-variables-at-once-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
a = b = c = d = 4
```

DEMO:

```
>>> a = b = c = d = 4
>>> a
4
>>> b
4
>>> c
4
>>> d
4
```

Comment: oh crap, you can do that? thanks for your help I know it seems trivial.